# Analysis - proof about inverses being bijective

Tags: real-analysis

"**Problem 1.** Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$ be functions for which $f \circ g = id_B$ and $g \circ f = id_A$. Prove that this implies that both $f$ and $g$ are bijective. Furthermore, show that given $f$ such a function $g$, if it exists, is unique."

It's obvious that $f$ and $g$ are inverse functions, which makes them bijective.. but this is a fact I've accepted and never actually had to prove. I can easily argue that for all $x \in A$ that $f(g(x)) = x$, and thus if $|A| = n$ then we have $n$ distinct $x$ that are all mapped uniquely. However, I don't know how to break this down into an argument about $f$ (or $g$) itself, which is what I need to show they are bijective.

Comment: hey bill cook: how do you make my image into the text like that?

Comment: You much use $\LaTeX$. Click "edit" or look at the source code to see how I typed it in. (There is no automatic way to do it - that I know of.)

Answer (score 1):

A function is called bijective if it is both [one-to-one (injective)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and [onto (surjective)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function). So you need to show $f$ is one-to-one and onto (and the same is true for $g$).

To show a function is one-to-one you need to show that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $x=y$ for all $x,y \in A$. [Hint: Compose $f$ with $g$.]

Next, you need to show $f$ is onto. Take an arbitrary element $y \in B$. You need to find some $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. [Hint: Map $y$ backwards with $g$.]

Similar arguments will take care of $g$.

Finally, uniqueness means that "[there can be only one.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander%3a_The_Series)" To show uniqueness one usually assumes there are two and then shows they are equal. So suppose $h$ also satisfies the same properties as $g$. Then prove that $h(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in B$.

I hope this helps get you started!

Comment: i don't know where to go from the function composition, though. let $x \in A$, we know that $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$, and let $y \in B$, we know that $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y$, but I don't know how to break this down to a single function rather than composition.

Comment: You have $f(x)=f(y)$ so then it must be that $x=g(f(x))=g(f(y))=y$. Therefore, $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense, and surjectivity was easy. now i am on the second part: to show that g is unique given f. how do i do this?

Comment: Well, first find some open spot away from observers. Certainly, take care to avoid Holy ground. Also, go for a nice clean cut. Then iterate.

Comment: You should assume there is some function $h(x)$ such that $h(f(x))=x$ and $f(h(x))=x$ for all $x \in A$. Then use that fact to show that $h(y)=g(y)$ for all $y \in B$. This implies that $h=g$ and so there is only one inverse (it's unique).